# With scale_size_area, add lines from top and bottom to next area point

Tags: r, ggplot2

The title is inartful, but let me explain.  My goal is to have a line from the top of the large "Hold" circle (at 12:00) to the top of the "Back" circle (at 12:00), and so on down.  Then also a line from the bottom of the large circle (6:00) to the bottom of the next largest circle, and so on.  Is the addition of such lines possible without placing segments manually?  Thank you.

```
# example data frame
df <- data.frame(Documents = c(1.5e5, .6e5, .3e5, .1e5), stages = c("Hold", "Back", "Trust", "Camp"), x = c(12, 18, 25, 35), y = c(10, 8, 7, 6))

library("ggplot2")
library(ggthemes)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, size = Documents)) +
  geom_point(color = "grey30", alpha = 0.3) + theme_tufte() +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 35) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = stages), size = 6, color = "red") + 
  theme(axis.text = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "Documents") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  xlim(8, 38) + ylim(5, 13)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think so, at least not with anything built-in. The only approach I can think of involves partially building the plot to force all the scales to be trained, and then pulling apart the trained scale information to determine what the radius of each circle is (in appropriate units), then use that to figure out where the top and bottom of the circle are, and use that to specify the ends of the segments. Not at all trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt that takes the plot generated by `ggplot` but then draws the lines inside a viewport with the same scales as the ggplot plot panel. `ggplot`'s internal data gives the size of the circles in points - I think. I think it is the radius of the circle. Thus to get the top and bottom of the circle, I needed to add and subtract "native" units to "points" units.  I don't know of a way to do that in `ggplot` proper, but it can be done in `grid`; hence the viewports.

But you will note that the lines (and points) are not exactly on the circumference of all circles - not sure of the reason.

I made one minor change to your ggplot - `expand = c(0,0)` on the two axes so that the viewport can be given the same scales as the plot panel.

```
# example data frame
df <- data.frame(Documents = c(1.5e5, .6e5, .3e5, .1e5), stages = c("Hold", "Back", "Trust", "Camp"), x = c(12, 18, 25, 35), y = c(10, 8, 7, 6))

library("ggplot2")
library(ggthemes)
library(grid)

p = ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, size = Documents)) +
  geom_point(color = "grey30", alpha = 0.3)  + theme_tufte() +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 35) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = stages), size = 6, color = "red") + 
  theme(axis.text = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "Documents") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(8,38), expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(5,13), expand = c(0,0))

p

# Get the size of the dots from ggplot's internal data.
# I think "size" is radius in "pts".
g = ggplot_build(p)
df$size = g$data[[1]]$size

# Set up viewport for the plot panel
current.vpTree() # Find the plot panel
downViewport("panel.6-4-6-4")

# Set up scales in the plot panel - see "limits" in ggplot
pushViewport(dataViewport(yscale = c(5,13), xscale = c(8,38)))

# Draw points and lines 
grid.points(x = unit(df$x, "native"), y = unit(df$y, "native") + unit(df$size, "pt"), pch = 19, gp = gpar(col = "blue", cex = .5), default.units = "native") 
grid.points(x = unit(df$x, "native"), y = unit(df$y, "native") - unit(df$size, "pt"), pch = 19, gp = gpar(col = "blue", cex = .5), default.units = "native") 
grid.lines(x = unit(df$x, "native"), y = unit(df$y, "native") + unit(df$size, "pt"), gp = gpar(col = "blue", lwd = 2), default.units = "native") 
grid.lines(x = unit(df$x, "native"), y = unit(df$y, "native") - unit(df$size, "pt"), gp = gpar(col = "blue", lwd = 2), default.units = "native") 

popViewport()
popViewport()
popViewport()
```

[image]